# Compress an 'If' Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

Hoping that this one doesn't cause much trouble in answering, but when writing this out in my Sudoku project, I knew there must be a better way of phrasing this if condition.

Thanks in advance guys.

```
public static void modVal(int r, int c, int x) {
    if((r>=1 && r<=9) && (c>=1 && c<=9) && (x>=1 && x<=9)) {
        sudoku.set(r,c,x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in `(c>=1 && r<=9)`

Comment: `if((r>=1 && r<=9) && (c>=1 && r<=9) && (x>=1 && x<=9))` you have r<=9 in the second condition. It seems like it should be c<=9

Comment: You can extract the condition into a method and give that method an intuitive name.  What does `modVal` mean?  What do `r`, `c`, and `x` mean?  Give things meaningful names, and you can arrive at a name for a method.  Basically, if you were to state the condition in English, what would it sound like?  "If *what* is true"?

Comment: Ugly and hard to read.  Easy to get wrong.

Comment: If you're too worried about it looking ugly, you can always write a private method with the same conditions. That way the code reads nicely and you does the same function.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @JohnnyMopp

Comment: My method is building a sudoku board, and as such, the values have to be within 1 and 9 for each block. @David

Comment: In terms of handling, it would probably be better to through an IllegalArgumentException if r,c, or x were not between 1-9.

Comment: Yes, better to use meaningful variable names. row, column and value rather than r, c and x.

Comment: I try to stay away from r,c,x in the method itself, but like to use one letter arguments and then set variables like row, column, value to those arguments

Answer (score 7):

You could pull out the logic into Boolean values and just test those instead e.g.

```
boolean validRow = r >= 1 && r <= 9;
boolean validColumn = c >= 1 && c <= 9;
boolean validValue = x >= 1 && x <= 9;
if (validRow && validColumn && validValue) {
    sudoku.set(r, c, x);
}
```

Or, given that the limits are identical for each (row, column and value all inclusively 1-9), then you could extract that to a method called `withinLimits(value)` that checks for the value being between 1 and 9.

```
public boolean withinLimits(int value) {
    return value >= 1 && value <= 9;
}
```

Then...

```
if (withinLimits(r) && withinLimits(c) && withinLimits(x)) {
    sudoku.set(r, c, x);
}
```

Not a great deal better than what you have though, just a little more terse syntactically speaking. And you don't require the additional parentheses either. Just drop them.

Comment: That is something I can work with, great idea @ManoDestra implementing now.

Comment: @element11 I use this technique a lot to improve readability of lengthy Boolean conditions in construct tests. Makes for shorter lines of code and allows you to analyze the logic quicker by breaking it down into smaller units.

Comment: @taylanu Are you happy to accept any of the answers given to you so far? :)

Answer (score 6):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

If you're using java 8, there is a way using an `IntStream`. The advantage is that you could use this with any number of parameters.

```
public static void modVal(int r,int c,int x){
    if (IntStream.of(r,c,x).allMatch(i -> i>=1 && i<=9)) {
        sudoku.set(r,c,x);
    }
}
```

---

### Explaination

```
Instream.of(r,c,x) // This will just stream over the data given in parameters.
        .allMatch(Predicate) // This will return true if all the data entered as parameter has been tested within Predicate and returned true.
```

Comment: I am using Java 8, and this solution seems even more effective, but at the same time, I feel like I'll struggle with debugging in the future with that implementation.

Comment: @taylanu Why do you think so?

Comment: Readability concerns for me, I am just starting out with Java, so I likely would struggle with understanding what your implementation would do.

Comment: @taylanu My bad. I'll add an explaination to this.